# Matrix rotation of elements 90 degrees, does it have a name and what could it be used for?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, soft-question

This operation:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\end{array}\right] \to \left[\begin{array}{ccc}7&4&1\\8&5&2\\9&6&3\end{array}\right]$$

That is, to rotate all elements in a matrix by 90 degrees around the center point. Have you encountered it in any context? Does it have any name?

---

I am curious because I suspect this other operation discussed in another question I can't quite find right now could be built with it:  ( Doing "transpose" but across the "northeast-southwest"-diagonal instead of the "northwest-southeast" diagonal ).

Comment: It's a transpose followed by a permutation of the columns. I doubt that it has a name, or any use.

Comment: The transpose across the NE-SW diagonal is discussed at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195031/is-there-a-standard-notation-for-off-diagonal-transpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The telephone matrix $A$ is first mapped to its transpose $A^T$, and then multiplied from the right by the permutation matrix
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 1 & 0 \cr 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
One "encounters it" in exam questions on the rank of matrices. Indeed, the telephone matrix has rank $2$, and the tranpose-column permutation leaves the rank invariant.

Comment: Oh I see now that it actually is a flipped phone. How funny.

Comment: I am reminded of the old joke, "The number you have dialed is imaginary. Please, rotate your phone by 90 degrees and try again."